# Answers locking due to low quality comments also prevents upvotes. What to do about it?

Tags: discussion, answers

Yesterday, I have read [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/28334/11278), I liked and tried to upvote it. However, a rather ugly error message told me that it is locked.

While I can understand the reason for locking the post, it also prevents users from voting and the author from getting points for what I think it is a good answer.

**Question:** Is there a way to have a more specific locking? (e.g. do not allow comments, but allow voting)

Comment: I find it even more annoying when it prevents down-voting low-quality/bad/wrong answers. Unfortunately this is how the system works at the moment; things like comments-only and edit-only locks have been proposed in the past, but never implemented by the SE people

Answer (score 11):

I have been asking for a [comments-only lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171223/can-we-get-a-comments-only-lock) for years. There might be [some hope](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171223/can-we-get-a-comments-only-lock#comment964088_171223) we will eventually get one. Right now, however, I'm afraid there is no good solution.

The answer produced an inordinate amount of comments that violated our [commenting guidelines](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). There were two requests for commenters to continue the discussion in chat, but unfortunately, both were ignored. Locking the answer was the only option left to stop the stream of off-topic comments.

(I unlocked the answer after a couple of days.)

Comment: "There were two requests for commenters to continue the discussion in chat" - I can only see one, [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/28319/why-is-the-british-government-so-determined-to-arrest-julian-assange/28334#comment105940_28334). Was the other one deleted?

Comment: Unless you're referring to "Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been moved to chat".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced of the merits of a comment-only lock feature. It means that someone can post a seemingly good answer, and get upvotes for it, but be immune to receiving comments pointing out problems with the answer. As this stack exchange's policy is not to delete answers merely for being poorly sourced (unlike Skeptics.SE), critical comments are very important.

The answer discussed in the answer currently has 19 downvotes, which suggest that a wide variety of people had issues with the answer, not just one or two people. By means of comparison, [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/28324/270), which received slightly more votes, only had 4 downvotes.

Comment: I have rarely seen locked answers, since this seems to be moderators' desperate measure to prevent comment flooding. When you have dozens and dozens of comments for an answer, it is hard to understand the constructive criticism.